# How to count and populate values from two different dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
col1=['aa_1','aa_1','aa_1','aa_2','aa_2','bb_2','bb_2','bb_3','bb_3','bb_3','cc_1','cc_1','cc_3','cc_3']

df1=pd.DataFrame({'col1':col1})

df1['col1']=['aa_1','aa_1','aa_1','aa_2','aa_2','bb_2','bb_2','bb_3','bb_3','bb_3','cc_1','cc_1',
              'cc_3','cc_3']

col2=['aa_3','aa_3','aa_3','bb_1','bb_1','bb_1','cc_2','cc_2', 'cc_2']

df2=pd.DataFrame({'col2':col2})

df2['col2']=['aa_3','aa_3','aa_3','bb_1','bb_1','bb_1','cc_2','cc_2',
              'cc_2']
```

I want to add the column values from df2['col2'] to df1['col1'] depending on the value count in df1. For example

- if value count of **'aa_2'** < value count of **'aa_1'** in **df1** then all of 'aa_3' in df2 should be added in 'aa_2' in df1 also changing their name to 'aa_2' as well and
- same logic as described above for 'bb'
- **'cc_2'** in **df2** should be added into 'cc_1' in df1 if count of cc_1 and cc_3 is equal

conditions must be checked in df1 and if a condition is met then values from df2 should be added to the df1['col1']

```
#Expected output should look like as follow


df1['col1']=['aa_1','aa_1','aa_1','aa_2','aa_2','bb_2','bb_2','bb_3','bb_3','bb_3','cc_1','cc_1',
              'cc_3','cc_3','aa_2','aa_2','aa_2','bb_2','bb_2','bb_2','cc_1','cc_1',
              'cc_1']
```

**Col1** and **col2** and from two **different data frames** and their column lengths are **different**

Is there is a way to do this in pandas DataFrame? I have 100,000 rows like this to add from df2 to df1.

Comment: Please include samples of `df1` and `df2` and you're expected output.

Comment: Do the two Dataframes have "commensurable" indexes?    Then you could first join the two Dataframes on the index, then implement your logic on the result.

Comment: No, the indexes are not commensurable. They are 0,1,2,3..... for both and are not into consideration when counting the values of the columns

Comment: Explain us how to group (aa_1, aa_2), (bb_2, bb_3), ... I think this are not the real names. If I split the name in 2 [(aa, 1), (aa, 2)], I'm pretty sure it will not working for your case. If the value counts of 2 groups are equal, how to determine which group receive the values from df2?

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 are the sizes in aa_1,aa_2, bb_2 etc and if the value count is the same in both groups then values go to df1 in any size e.g if aa_1 count = aa_2 count in df1 the aa_3 count can be added in either aa_1 or aa_2 it does not matter for equal count.

Comment: I understood that but how to make groups: in the real case, what if the name of `aa_1`, `aa_2`, `bb_1`, `bb_3`? Can I split `aa_1`into `aa` and `1` to create group `aa`?

Comment: yes sir, you can split them like that.

Comment: I'm sorry to annoying you but *"...'aa_2' in df1 also changing their name to 'aa_2' as well and"* -> **'aa_2'** or **'aa_3'** ?